# How to stop the loop for Javascript scroll down?

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript code for the F12 console to automatically scroll down. It works fine, but I want it to stop after 250 times. How to do that?

```
var scroll = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0,1000); }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var count = 1;
var scroll = setInterval(() =>  this.executeInterval(), 10);

function executeInterval() {
   window.scrollBy(0,1000); 
   console.log(count)
   if(count == 250) clearInterval(scroll);

   count++;
}
```

Forgot the function. press on run code snippet.

Comment: I tried it with 10 laps and unfortunately it still doesn't stop

Comment: edited my inital post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clearInterval()` to cancel a repeating action which was established with `setInterval()`.

Read the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var scroll = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0,1000); }, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
   clearInterval(scroll)
}, 250 * 2000)
```

Comment: it not work....